# How application insight judges the same user when using webchat?

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-analytics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), retention tracks how many users who sent one message came back later and sent another one.

How about webchat? My webchat doesn't have "login in" feature. How the application insight judges the same users? Or it can't when using webchat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a unique user id from storage - local storage, session storage, or a database depending on your needs - as a prop to Web Chat, which should get picked up by App Insights.

```
let { userID } = localStorage;

// if userID doesn't exist, create one.
if (!userID) {
  userID = Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36);
  localStorage['userID'] = userID;
}

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
store,
userID
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is just for the first day. how about the second day? according to your option, i have to set the same userid if it is the same user. Right?

Comment: Date.now() should return a number down to the millisecond, so in theory, each id will be unique.

Comment: @Jeff_hu I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: The first day, the userID is 20190621XXXXXXX.
The second day, the userID is 20190622XXXXXX.
This case, of course, they are not the same user, right?
So, it's difficult to track the same user, unless to memo the first day's user ID, and pass it to webchat in the second day, right?

Comment: I apologize - I misread your question. I've updated my answer. Basically you would need to store the user id somehow and pass that to Web Chat as a prop each time.